# cloth modifier on a t-shirt

Tags: animation

I've tried to apply a cloth modifier on a t-shirt so that it could fit properly on the body and followed its movements. The problem is that the t-shirt appears to be shaken by some wind, even if there isn't any force field enabled. Does anybody have any advice to give me?
Hope I made my self clear!

Comment: If the model the t-shirt is on is moving and a collision object, I'm going to guess the movement isn't wind, but the effect of the momentum of previous movements staying in the system. I'd suggest posting your cloth settings, but I'm guessing you need to look specifically at the "damping setting" on the right side of the cloth settings

Comment: I fixed the problem, thank you. Now I got another one: in my animation there's a girl who goes on her knees quite fast. As soon as she starts going down, the body trespass the clothes which keep descending but much slower than the body and without following it.

Comment: The settings you'll want to look at for that is the collision distance and quality of the collision (which is like a resolution for collision detection).  Increasing collision quality will increase simulation time.

I've also submitted the above comment as an answer. If that is what  helped you, please accept it as the answer -- thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the model the t-shirt is on is moving and a collision object, I'm going to guess the movement isn't wind, but the effect of the momentum of previous movements staying in the system. I'd suggest posting your cloth settings, but I'm guessing you need to look specifically at the "damping setting" on the right side of the cloth settings.